# Correcting a Rebbe who is learning during חזרת הש"ץ

Tags: halacha, adult-learning, kavod, rebuke-tochacha, chazarat-hashatz

Is it better to tell my Rebbe that he can't learn during חזרת הש"ץ or is it better to respect him.

Comment: the question of the propriety of learning at that time is something people argue about, using deuling sources http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/learning-during-chazoras-hashatz

Comment: To mimic @DoubleAA, why do you think it would be more proper to do one or the other? Why do you think learning during חזרת הש"ץ warrants telling your Rebbe (or anyone) anything?

Comment: I think in general, one should be _very_ hesitant to "correct" his rebbe on anything

Comment: This also applies to someone who 'changes' t'fillin during chazoras hashats against the kitsur. I think one has to correct him so that others shouldnt learn from him. This is similar to chillul hashem where respect doesnt apply. One could send him an anonymous letter. The same applies if he regularly comes late. Children will learn from him to do the same.

Comment: Who said it's assur? Obviously the accepted viewpoint is not to. But I have seen gedolie ugeonei Yisroel learning during חזרת הש"ץ. See igros Moshe on this.

Comment: @Daniel if he is doing something wrong why not? Is a rav above halacha? Obviously one must know the sources well before hand but if it's a clear thing of course one should

Comment: @mefaresh I didn't say that there is no case where one should correct his rebbe. Still I think it's usually unlikely to safely assume that you know something he doesn't.

Comment: Even where the Rebbe is certainly wrong, you are supposed to ask in an honorable way 'doesn't rebbi say this is the halacha?'. But again, that is where he is certainly wrong.

Comment: @user6591 A peripheral benefit of that approach is that it is an appropriate mode of inquiry even if the rebbe is right.

Answer (score 5):

See Igros Moshe (או"ח ד' סימן יט'):

> **עיון בספר בזמן חזרת הש"ץ עש"ק ד' אייר תשל"ד**. מע"כ ידידי הנכבד מאד מו"ה  ר' זלמן אריה הילזענראד שליט"א. הנה בדבר עיון בספר בזמן חזרת הש"ץ, **עיין
>   במג"א סימן קכ"ד סק"ח שהביא מתשובת מ"ע דהאנשים שלומדים בעת חזרת הש"ץ
>   התפלה אם מכוונים לסוף הברכה לענות אמן כראוי אין למחות בידם**, משמע שסובר
>   דכל השתיקה היא רק כדי שיוכל לומר אמן שלזה סגי בכוונה לידע סוף הברכה על
>   מה עונה אמן, שלכן סובר שליכא איסור ואין למחות בידם, אך מסיק דבספר ווי
>   העמודים קרא תגר עליהם וציין ]שו"ע או''ח[ לסימן צ' סעי' י"ח שכתב שם
>   הרמ"א לענין אחר דאפילו מי שתורתו אומנתו שמדינא יש לו להתפלל בבית המדרש
>   שקבע ללמוד בו אפילו בלא עשרה דאפ"ה לא ירגיל עצמו לעשות כן שלא ילמדו
>   עמי הארץ ממנו ויתבטלו מבית הכנסת וגם מסיק וכ"ש שלא יעסוק בתורה בבהכ"נ
>   בזמן שהצבור אומרים סליחות ותחנונים ויליף משם גם ללמוד בזמן חזרת הש"ץ
>   שאף שהוא עושה כדין מ"מ לא יעשה כן ומוחים בו כדי שלא ילמדו אחרים ממנו
>   והם לא יכוונו גם לסוף הברכה, עיין במחצה"ש ובפמ"ג שפירשו כן כוונת
>   המג"א. **אבל לע"ד נראה דהוא רק כשאיכא עשרה ששומעין חזרת הש"ץ ולא מפסיקין
>   כלל שלהאחרים הם סוברים שמותר מדינא ללמוד לאלו שיוכלו לכוין לסוף הברכה
>   לענות אמן אי לאו הא דילמדו אחרים ממנו, אבל כשליכא עשרה אסור מדינא**, דהא
>   תקנת חזרת הש"ץ היתה לאלו שהיה מוציא אותם בתפלת י"ח, ומפורש כן בסעיף ג'
>   דכתב קהל שהתפללו וכולם בקיאין בתפלה אעפ"כ ירד ש"ץ וחוזר להתפלל כדי
>   לקיים תקנת חכמים, והוא מתשובת הרמב"ם שהביא הב"י מהר"ד אבודרהם עיי"ש,
>   וא"כ הרי צריך להיות ממש כפי התקנה שתיקנו להוציא את שאינו בקי דצריך
>   דוקא שישמעו לכל מה שאומר הש"ץ וצריך שיהיו עשרה השומעין דוקא דהא תפלת
>   י"ח אין יכול אחד להוציא את חברו כדאיתא בירושלמי פ"ג דברכות ה"ג ר' יוסי
>   ור' אדא בן פזי הוו מתיבין אמרו לא מסתברא בק"ש שיהא כל אחד משנן בפיו לא
>   מסתברא בתפלה שיהא כל אחד ואחד מבקש רחמים על עצמו והובא בר"ן סוף ר"ה
>   ד"ה יחיד, אבל בשביל האינם בקיאין תיקנו ענין חדש דתפלה ע"י ש"ץ שהוא
>   דוקא בעשרה ובתפלה זו יוצאין מצות תפלה האינם בקיאין, וחייבו זה לכל
>   צבור, והארכתי בענין זה בחדושי בסוף ראש השנה, וזהו מש"כ הטור שם מתשובת
>   הרא"ש דכשאין תשעה המכוונים בברכות ש"צ קרוב בעיני להיות ברכת ש"ץ לבטלה
>   כי נתקנה ברכות ש"ץ לאומרם בעשרה, וזה שכתב קרוב אבל לא ממש עיין בדרישה
>   בשם הב"י דהוא משום דאם התחילו בעשרה גומר הש"ץ אף כשיצאו מקצתן, משמע
>   דבתחלה כשלא יכוונו עשרה לברכות הש"ץ יהיה ממש ברכה לבטלה, ואף אם לא
>   יכוונו עשרה לשאר הברכות הרי הם ממילא לפ"ז כאילו יצאו שאיתא בירושלמי על
>   היוצאין בפ"ד ממגילה ה"ד ועל כולם הוא אומר ועזבי ה' יכלו והובא ברי"ף
>   וברא"ש שם, והוא דוקא כשלא הניחו עשרה כדאיתא ברמ"א ]או''ח[ סימן נ"ה
>   סעי' ב' בשם המרדכי, וא"כ הטעם הוא על שגרם שיאמר הש"ץ שאר הברכות בלא
>   עשרה, שממילא כיון שמי שאינו מכוין להש"ץ אינו נמנה מהעשרה ומה שאינו
>   לבטלה הוא משום דגומר גם ביצא הרי א"כ גם לענין חשיבות ועוזבי ה' נמי יש
>   להחשיבו כיצא לכאורה. שלכן מוכרחין לומר דתשובת מ"ע הוא רק באיכא עשרה
>   מכוונין להש"ץ סובר דאין למחות בידם אף שאין עושין כהוגן דהא כל אדם צריך
>   לעשות עצמו כאילו אין ט' זולתו, ובמג"א מסיק בשם ווי העמודים דגם צריך
>   למחות מטעם שילמדו ממנו, אבל כשליכא ט' אסור מדינא אף שיכול לכוין לסוף
>   הברכה ולענות אמן ויקרא בשם ועוזבי ה', **ולכן אסור ללמוד בשעת חזרת הש"ץ
>   בכל אופן יש מדינא ויש מטעם המג"א**. והנני ידידו, משה פיינשטיין

Rav Moshe concludes that despite the fact that there are justifications to allow learning during the repetition of the Shmona Esrei, eg. There is for  sure a minyan answering, or he himself is sure to answer amen.  Nonetheless one should make as if the minyan is dependant on him and not learn lest he not answer, and further he should take care to not set a wrong example.

It would seem to be that there a basis to say something to the rebbe, especially if others will learn from him. But one could also argue that since there is a basis to allow it tacitly maybe you should not say anything to the Rebbe. But maybe it is worthwhile to show this Rav Moshe and ask him to explain to you and through that the Rebbe will realize by himself what the correct thing is.

However as always here on Mi Yodeya, consult a halachic authority.